# How do I stop Dragon Naturally Speaking Version 15.60 from changing "first" to "1st" automatically? Same thing when I say "second", "third", etc

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

trying to find a way to stop Dragon NaturallySpeaking version 15.60 changing "first", "second" "third" to 1st, 2nd, 3rd...  I tried using New Auto Text in the Tools but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=8412

In the formatting options check the box saying "Number if greater than or equal to..." and then set the number to 0.  Then you will always get numerals.

Setting it to 100 or so should do the opposite.